# Clone SharePoint VM containing SQL DB on different Box

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, clone

I have a SharePoint 2010 Setup in a VM. And Content DB of central admin of this server, say "Server A" resides on "DB Server 1". Now i clone the VM and create another copy say "Server B". I changed IP, renamed servername and also corrected Alternate access mapping. But how do i select different database for central admin for "Server B"?As it still points to "DB Server 1" and hence "Server A" central admin opens up even if i click central admin on "Servr B"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

Create an isolated network

Clone an existing Domain Controller into the isolated network

Forcefully remove all other DCs from this cloned domain

Shutdown SharePoint Server(s) + SQL Server, create copy.

Bring copy up in the isolated network. Never, ever let the copy of SharePoint 'see' the production network.

Comment: In this situation, where will the central admin of cloned SP point to ?I mean which DataBase? How to change it to point to the copied sql server?

Comment: You don't. Everything will have the same name, paths, and so forth. This is why you _must_ have an isolated network.

Comment: So i i will have to put sql + sp in one box? Actually i want to ask is it possible to put db of both copies in another server? i.e examples from question, on "DB server 1", we have DB for "Server A" and "Server B"?

Comment: It sounds like you might be confused. You would have an _exact copy_ of your SharePoint server(s) and one Domain Controller in this isolated network. You could have a different SQL Server (built new in the isolated network) and restore the appropriate SharePoint databases. If you do that, you'll need to use cliconfg.exe on your SharePoint servers to remap the existing SQL Server name to the new Server/Instance name. This is a really bad idea prone to mistakes. You should build a new farm and restore dbs instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you have to recreate the configuration database. If i am not wrong, Cloning is not supported( COnfig DB). You have to config wizard and recreate the configuration database and provision central admin.

Here is an article may help your situation.
http://spnotepad.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-clone-sharepoint-2010-hyper-v-vm.html

Comment: Thanks for inputs. But i need to create copy of existing setup. If SQL database was in same VM , copyin process is straightforward. But in this case, SQL is in diff box. So central admin is shared between two copies